# ccnx android java:not found

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make ccnx project on Android. I have already built ccnx on Linux successfully, but meet errors when do as the README for Android.

The errors say this:

```
make -C CCNx-Android-Lib -j 1
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/android/ccnx-0.6.0/android/CCNx-Android-Lib'
/home/android/android-sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/android update lib-project -p . -t android-7

/home/android/android-sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/android: 84: java: not found
/home/android/android-sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/android: 101: java: not found
exec: 114: java: not found
make[1]: \*** [project.properties] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/android/ccnx-0.6.0/android/CCNx-Android-Lib'
make: \*** [CCNx-Android-Lib] Error 2
```

I have checked `JAVA_HOME PATH JRE_HOME CLASSPATH`, but do not have some way to solve this.

```
Java -version 1.6.0_27

Java enviroment
\#set JDK environment
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_27
export PATH=$PATH:/home/android/jdk1.6.0_27/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$CLASSPATH
export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe that your problem is reported by these warnings:

> /home/android/android-sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/android: 84: java: not found
>   /home/android/android-sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/android: 101: java: not found
>   exec: 114: java: not found

Check to see if the files exist and if the file permissions are correctly set.

Comment: Please see my improved answer

Comment: the file exists and permission 777,but the problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

It is actually the `dalvik machine` problem. you will `restart` the `emulator` and `eclipse` and try. hopes it works.
check all dalvik files.

i am not yet tried in emulator.

while i am using `rooted device` i found this, so i `restart` the `device`. it works fine.